# Kotlin: How to fetch data from web service and display it in app?

Tags: api, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Hello :) I'm working on app that shows popular movies and some details about each of them. I created a RecyclerView where information should be displayed. I'm stuck with getting and displaying data. I'm using https://www.themoviedb.org/ page for api.

I was following these steps: http://imakeanapp.com/make-a-movies-app-using-tmdb-api-part-4-networking-using-retrofit-library/ , but it's written in Java and I need code in Kotlin. I converted by myself a part of the code, here is what I have:

in Movie.kt

```
data class Movie (
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
    @SerializedName("poster_path") val posterPath: String,
    @SerializedName("release_date") val releaseDate: String,
    @SerializedName("vote_average") val rating: Float
)
```

in MoviesResponse.kt

```
data class MoviesResponse (
    @SerializedName("page") val page: Int,
    @SerializedName("total_results") val totalResults: Int,
    @SerializedName("results") val movies: List<Movie>,
    @SerializedName("total_pages") val totalPages: Int
)
```

in TMDbApi.kt

```
interface TMDbApi {
    @GET("movie/popular")

    fun getPopularMovies (
        @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
        @Query("language") language: String,
        @Query("page") page: Int
    ): Call<List<MoviesResponse>>
}
```

in OnGetMoviesCallback.kt

```
interface OnGetMoviesCallback {
    fun onSuccess(movies: List<Movie>)
    fun onError()
}
```

in MainAdapter.kt

```
class MainAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomHolder>(){

    var movies: List<Movie> = listOf()

    fun MainAdapter(movies: List<Movie>) {
        this.movies = movies
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(movies.get(position))
        holder?.setOnClick()
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_row, parent, false)
        return CustomHolder(cellForRow)
    }
}
class CustomHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bind(result: Movie){
        itemView.title.text = result.title
        itemView.release_date.text = result.releaseDate
    }
}
```

in MoviesRepository.kt

```
val BASE_URL: String = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"
val LANGUAGE: String = "en-US"

data class MoviesRepository (
    val repositroy: MoviesRepository,
    val api: TMDbApi
)
object getInstance{
    val retrofit: TMDbApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(TMDbApi::class.java)
}
```

in AllMoviesActivity.kt

```
class AllMoviesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Callback<List<MoviesResponse>> {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_movies)

        rw_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rw_main.adapter = MainAdapter()

        getMovies()
    }

    private fun getMovies() {
        getInstance.retrofit.getPopularMovies("2B0b0e8d104f0d6130a4fc67848f89e107", LANGUAGE, 1).enqueue(this)
    }
    override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<List<MoviesResponse>>, response: Response<List<MoviesResponse>>) {
        val moviesResponse = response.body() ?: listOf()
        Log.d("Results", moviesResponse.toString())
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<List<MoviesResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And I have added in Manifest file Internet permission. When I run this, I get 'Failed' Toast and I don't see RecyclerView. Can you tell me what I'm missing or what's wrong? I've been searching on the Internet solutions but with no results. Hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging the `Throwable` from the `onFailure` callback to see what's going on? If yes, what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing something small. After making a call to the API on *Postman*, Here's what you expect on your response body:

```
{
"page": 1,
"total_results": 10000,
"total_pages": 500,
"results": [...
}
```

Having brought that up, lets digest your lines, in *TMDbApi.kt*, you have indicated that your expected response is a `List<MoviesResponse>` which conflicts the response you receive as it is a JSON of type `MoviesResponse`,
Fix:

```
 ...): Call<List<MoviesResponse>>
}
```

to:

```
    ): Call<MoviesResponse>
}
```

The rest are small fixes to align your response handling.

Head over to *AllMoviesActivity.kt* and change the following:

```
class AllMoviesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Callback<List<MoviesResponse>> {
```

to

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Callback<MoviesResponse>
```

Then on the callback functions, change signatures like so:

```
 override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<List<MoviesResponse>>, response: Response<List<MoviesResponse>>) {
            val moviesResponse = response.body() ?: listOf() ...
```

to:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<MoviesResponse>, response:Response<MoviesResponse>
     ) {
       val moviesResponse = response.body()//type will be inferred ...
```

Then finally,

```
override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<List<MoviesResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
```

to:

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesResponse>, t: Throwable) {
```

That's the basic to get the response and keep the *Failure* toast at bay.

### Parting shot

Make the logs your friend, they can reveal the messy & smallest misses